# Jar files: why does extracting then compression a jar file create a file of a different size to the original?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, jar, eclipse-plugin

I was trying to edit a single byte in an extracted Eclipse plugin jar file. I noticed that after I re-compressed the files as a jar, the resultant file was larger than the original (only 1%) and that the plugin didn't work. Eclipse booted, but shut down silently after selecting a workspace. Rolling back to the original plugin allowed it to start successfully.

I then tried uncompressing, then compressing the plugin (not changing anything) and the resultant jar file was still bigger than the original, and also didn't work.

```
$ jar -xf temp/in.jar
```

then

```
$ jar -cf out.jar temp/*

$ du in.jar out.jar
4216    in.jar
4236    out.jar
```

I guess this might be due to timestamps being changed, but I didn't think that this would stop eclipse from accepting it.

So my question: Is there a way to uncompress a jar, change a byte, and compress it without changing the jar significantly?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 - 64 bit:

```
Linux user 2.6.32-38-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:12:07 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When looking at the jar's table, there appears to be a different order:

```
$ jar tf in.jar | head -n 5
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/android/
com/android/ide/

$ jar tf out.jar | head -n 5
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
about.html
about.ini
about.properties
```

Is there a way to order them differently within the jar?

Comment: To reitterate, you want to change bytes IN THE ACTUAL BYTES of the Jar file, not those in the .class files (as in altering bytecode)?

Comment: This "requirement" is bogus (and absurd) - it is highly unlikely your goal is to change a byte in a jar. What are you *actually* trying to do? Maybe we can help you find a better approach than your "solution".

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity. I wish to change a byte in one of the class files in the jar by whatever method possible. If that means extracting it, altering it, and recompressing - that's great ( currently I can't get this to work). If I could byte alter the original jar file, and it worked I would be satisfied. My goal is the result and if I can get it by an 'absurd' method, I'll take it. I'm trying to alter ADT as per this [post](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-4-customizing-adt/)

Comment: I'm getting around the issue but rebuilding ADT from source (after changing the access rule), but I'm still curious as to why the jar changes size and wonder why eclipse didn't accept the altered jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obtaining a different size after recompression is normal if one file has been modified. But if nothing has been modified, maybe you haven't the same root directory in both archives.

Run the following two commands and post the result here (the first lines only):

```
jar tf in.jar
jar tf out.jar
```

These commands list all files in Jar files with their path.

Have you tried to update only the modified file using the following command:

```
jar uf in.jar TheFileYouModified
```

TheFileYouModified must be the same path as in the JAR file. For example to replace com/android/Example.class you have extracted in /tmp/injar/ and modified :

```
jar uf in.jar -C /tmp/injar com/android/Example.class
```

Comment: I updated the post with the 'table' information. It can be seen that they're in different orders. Is there a way to reorder the jar? Since building from source is hitting it's own snags - I might try writing a small script to place the files in the jar in the same order and see how that goes.

Comment: Supplying a long line of the files in the same order as the in.jar manifest files, still produces a different manifest. Also using jar cmf Manifestfromin doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I updated my comment to ask you to try if simply updating one file would solve the problem with Eclipse.

Comment: Hi LD, that solved the problem. I now have an ADT version which blocks /interax/** instead of /internal/** . Thank you for the assistance :)

Comment: @Stu, can you please share your updated ADT version. I tried many times but still facing issues. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user623517 - I'm on a new computer at the moment so I don't have access to that jar. But it was using the above command - something like: jar uf com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_16.0.jar -C out/ com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/project/AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer.class - I hope that helps.