# How to update the JAR file with original settings?

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to update a `Kitchen.jar` file, but it refuses to work after an update. Here's what I did:

```
$ jar xf Kitchen.jar
$ jar uf Kitchen.jar com/package/Toster.class
```

All looks good. `opendiff` (as well as `jar tf`) shows **no difference**, however the file size is 1008 bytes different. The binary compare shows about 700 differences. And the jar doesn't work any more.

As you can see I did not change any files, I just did an extraction and updated the jar file with original untouched class file.

I've seen [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604622/jar-files-why-does-extracting-then-compression-a-jar-file-create-a-file-of-a-di) on SO, but that did not answer it, as my structure is not changed.

The original manifest has this:

```
Created-By: 1.7.0_05-b05 (Oracle Corporation)
```

While I have:

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_17
```

Have to say (however not sure if this is relevant) that the Jar file I'm trying to modify is part of Eclipse IDE plugin.

I have 2 thoughts:

1. This is because I'm on a Mac while the original jar was created on different platform.
2. This is because there were some [java runtime vars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#options) defined (jar`s -J option) while creating package.

This makes me think that I either need to find what platform it was created and try packaging it there, or find out what *-J*-options were defined during the packaging operation. Is it possible? How?

Comment: What do you mean by "the jar refuses to work"?

Comment: Could you please add the error messages related to `the jar doesn't work any more.`?

Comment: @Funtik, the Eclipse plugin stops working as expected and throws NPE and ULE at certain points. Although, the event logs do not show any errors in specific class or near. The system itself stops operating. The reason I ask — is because I know it's possible, because I have a working example of modified jar file for previous version of IDE. And using that older JAR file throws exceptions from expected classes.

Comment: So you are trying to launch an Eclipse plugin built for a different platform?

Comment: @ericson thanks, but I don't have the stack that leads to the jar of interest. Could you please read the previous comment as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Funtik not sure how to answer this, but I have mac-based eclipse distribution with bundled plugin. I'm extracting and repackaging it under Mac as well. The jar file of interest however, is known to work under all platforms. The problem occurs only when I try to repackage it keeping the source files unchanged.

Comment: There is a log file under `<eclipse_workspace>/.metadata/.log`, have you checked that?

Comment: Without any traces it's difficult to suggest anything. What you could try is to debug the jar file (I guess you do not have the source code of it, so you also need to use some sort of disassemble plugin for eclipse) Just import the jar as a source code, launch the eclipse in debug mode and hope for the best.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Why would you extract a class and put it back again the same?

Comment: @m0skit0 I did this to identify the problem-causing spot. I indeed was modifying one of the classes, but after it didn't work, I had to test out every step separately, which led me to the packaging step.